# Pair Eddystone-TLM with Eddystone-UID iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is there a way in iOS to match an Eddystone-TLM packet with an Eddystone-UID to identify the beacon, I want to use Eddystone-TLM to monitor the health of my fleet of beacons, but I don't find a way to do it in iOS.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the Eddystone-UID, URL, and TLM packets are all broadcast with the same physical/MAC address, specifically, on iOS, you’d use Core Bluetooth to detect these packets, and the CBPeripheral object has an identifier property, which is a scrambled MAC address of the beacon/Bluetooth peripheral. So in this case, I’d expect that for both the TLM and the UID packets, the CBPeripheral identifier would be the same.